# How to avoid automatic redirection to login page while scraping Facebook by Selenium

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

My setting options for Chrome are as below. Additionally, I also randomly generate time.sleep(random.randrange(3, 6, 1)) while scrolling. After several scrolls I'm not able to avoid this redirection to login page. Any idea how to bypass this login redirection? I'm not logged in to Facebook. Got **TimeoutException: Message:**

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['disable-logging', 'disable-popup-blocking'])
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
#options.add_argument('--headless')


driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
time.sleep(random.randrange(2, 10, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. So they are not going to make it easy. And no there is of course no way to bypass the login requirement

Answer (score 0):

There is no legal way to bypass the login form appearing on facebook if you are not logged in. Don't waste your time - just login in your tests.

Comment: Ok, let's try then. BTW Does anyone know how to define the post timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

This is not good practice in selenium , Please go through the seleniumHq site

For multiple reasons, logging into sites like Gmail and Facebook using WebDriver is not recommended. Aside from being against the usage terms for these sites (where you risk having the account shut down), it is slow and unreliable.

The ideal practice is to use the APIs that email providers offer, or in the case of Facebook the developer tools service which exposes an API for creating test accounts, friends, and so forth. Although using an API might seem like a bit of extra hard work, you will be paid back in speed, reliability, and stability. The API is also unlikely to change, whereas webpages and HTML locators change often and require you to update your test framework.

Logging in to third-party sites using WebDriver at any point of your test increases the risk of your test failing because it makes your test longer. A general rule of thumb is that longer tests are more fragile and unreliable.

WebDriver implementations that are W3C conformant also annotate the navigator object with a WebDriver property so that Denial of Service attacks can be mitigated.